# FrameReported analogue in win runtime framework

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to get all touches of the frame globally? I need to get all touch points from a current frame. Just like it may be done with Silverlight framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use Window.Current.CoreWindow with the event, for example :

Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindowOnPointerPressed;

```
private void CoreWindowOnPointerPressed(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_Tapped main");
    }
```

Comment: It does not work with ScrollView - you cannot track down moved pointer when it is under direct manipulation control.